# How can I fix the Error of Docker-compose up exited with code 1

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am beginner in Docker.
I have a simple DockerFile and Docker-compose.yml files
When I use docker-compose up, then it show an error which is exited with code 1
I do not know how can I fix it.
my DockerFile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ENV APP_HOME /home
RUN mkdir -p $APP_HOME
ADD target/spring-docker.jar $APP_HOME/spring-docker.jar
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java","-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://db:27017/","-jar","/home/spring-docker.jar"]
```

Docker-Compose:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    spring-docker:
        build: .
        restart: always
        ports: 
            - "8080:8080"
        depends_on:
           - db
    db:
        image: mongo
        volumes:
            - ./data:/data/db
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        restart: always
```

The SpringBoot is based application along with it’s mongodb database.

Comment: Exit Code 1 Indicates that the container stopped due to either an application error or an incorrect reference in Dockerfile to a file that is not present in the container.

Comment: yes, I know. but I think I did all correct and cannot understand where is my mistake inside my files

Comment: When you run the command what does terminal shows before giving Exit code 1?
Where are your DockerFile and docker-compose.yml in the directory?
You get it, there are lots of things which are not in question.

Comment: Can you paste the logs from docker-compose here

Comment: I am facing the same issue @saharsa, How did you fix it?

Answer (score 17):

docker may fail due to many things in the build process. To find the solution here is my advice

1. Type `docker ps -la` (to list all containers that exited with error code or failed to start
2. In the result, you should look out for the id of the container
3. Then check the logs using: `docker logs <container_id>`

Comment: You may now ask for clarifications using the comment or accept an answer

Comment: By using this tip, I was able to determine that the Linux container in my combined Windows+Linux containers Docker Compose setup was complaining about not being able to find the explicitly-defined network in the yml after a reboot. To resolve this, I removed that network definition altogether and let Docker handle it for me automatically. I believe I could have also created a permanent one and added `external: true` to its definition.

Answer (score 5):

Might seem a little vague and all, but I find that restarting docker always helps solve this issue.

If on Windows, `go to your ash tray, right click on docker icon, select restart`

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Reboot of windows, in my case, worked for me ... it solves a lot of issues most of the time, which still is rather sad ... :(